# How has the slogan "Bis in den Tod, Rot-Weiss-Rot" been used before and after the Anschluss, and in modern times?

Tags: world-war-two, nazism, austria, nationalism

I am curious about Austrian slogan *"Bis in den Tod! Rot-Weiss-Rot! Österreich!"*, usually rendered in English as *"Red-White-Red until we are dead!"*, where "Red-White-Red" refers to the colors of the Austrian flag.

The slogan was made famous by [the Austrian chancellor Kurt Schuschnigg's defiant speech against the Anschluss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Schuschnigg#Anschluss). However, it seems to be a rather generic slogan to be associated to this situation only - I would expect that that it has broader meaning in the context of Austrian nationalism. More specifically:

- Had the slogan been used before the Schuschnigg's speech, by whom and what it was supposed to mean then?
- Had it had extensive use in the aftermath of the Anschluss?
- How is it perceived today? - while being an anti-Nazi slogan, it is clearly a nationalist one (Schuschnigg himself was a religious conservative with dictatorial powers).

Comment: Perhaps include: 'And has it been used in other contexts, [like soccer](https://www.testedich.de/fantests/sport/fussball/fussballvereine/vfb-stuttgart/quiz30/1323804119/rot-weiss-rot-bis-in-den-tod)'? [Top-hit when searching on the net for me]

Comment: @LangLangC I think Google tailors its search results by country - I didn't see this one, but rather an old book on Anschluss and then the WIki artcile on Schuschnigg. Soccer fans are known to have their own political biases though.

Comment: And I didn't use Google… (Flag this one as obsolete at any time convenient)

Comment: @MCW is it better now?

Comment: @LangLangC Your link does not look particularly Austrian tho.

Comment: @Jan The language is the _very_ same and the symbolism equally vague. Such bombast popular with soccer fans? You may want to look at Kapfenberger, GAK, KSV Ankerbrot Montelaa, FS Elektra Wien… (In .de I'm sure it also applies to eg Erfurt & Essen fans?) Please flag most of this as obsolete now.

Comment: @RogerVadim - Someone could do a really ... kickin ... book on the historical intersection of soccer and politics.

Comment: @MCW is it better?

Comment: Better - although I have to point out that the current question is quite complex and that may put some people off.  The more effort it takes to parse the title, the less likely people are to  actually read the question.